# How can I make implicit to node which is not collection?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I want to convert this class in xml file of this type. What should I do to remove the node `<с>`? How can I make implicit to node which is not collection?

Java:

```
public class root {
    int a;
    int b;
    int d;
}
```

XML:

```
<root>
  <a>123</a>
  <b>345</b>
  <c>
     <d>567</d>
  </c>
</root>
```

Comment: I don't see how your Java class will result in this XML. Do you *want* to have the element `c`? Or *do* you want to have it? Why for `d`?

Comment: How did that `<c>` get into your XML? It is a mistery.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Converter for this. 
Create a class implementing com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter, and override its marshal and unmarshal methods: Adding an ugly example that serves the purpose.

```
class SimpleConverter implements Converter{
@Override
    public void marshal(Object o, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext marshallingContext) {
        Root i = (Root) o;
        writer.startNode("a");
        writer.setValue(String.valueOf(i.a));
        writer.endNode();
        writer.startNode("b");
        writer.setValue(String.valueOf(i.b));
        writer.endNode();
        writer.startNode("c");
        writer.startNode("d");
        writer.setValue(String.valueOf(i.d));
        writer.endNode();
        writer.endNode();

    }
@Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext unmarshallingContext) {
        Root root = new Root();
        reader.moveDown();
        root.a = Integer.valueOf(reader.getValue());
        reader.moveUp();
        reader.moveDown();
        root.b = Integer.valueOf(reader.getValue());
        reader.moveUp();
        reader.moveDown();
        reader.moveDown();
        root.d = Integer.valueOf(reader.getValue());
        reader.moveUp();
        reader.moveUp();
        return root;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class aClass) {
        return aClass.equals(Root.class);
    }
}

class Root {
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int d;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
        Root root = new Root();
        root.a = 1;
        root.b = 2;
        root.d = 3;
        XStream xStream = new XStream();
        xStream.registerConverter(new SimpleConverter());
        System.out.println(xStream.toXML(root));
        Root root1 = (Root) xStream.fromXML(xStream.toXML(root));
```